# Let's settle our differences

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, grid-deduction, formation-of-numbers

[image: Screenshot of a partially populated 4x4 grid. The top row is 89, blank, 13 and 5. The second row is 55, 21, blank and 3. The third row is blank, blank, 5 and blank. The fourth row is blank, 8, 3 and 1.]

Can you complete this grid and expose the existing relationships? There are no complex operations (e.g. no exponents, square roots, functions, etc), additionally the numbers are all natural numbers and all are less than 100.

---

This is my first [formation-of-numbers](/questions/tagged/formation-of-numbers) puzzle; hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we notice that

> A number and its top number sum to the left number, giving us:
>
> ```
>  89 34 13  5
>  55 21  8  3
>  34 13  5  2
>  21  8  3  1
> ```

And we're done!

Comment: Hopefully not *too* easy?

Comment: rot13(V fnj Svobanppv naq jrag sebz gurer :C) Might be a bit more difficult if you don't notice that right away.

Comment: Completely fair :) thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Equivalently, it's basically just rot13(gur Svobanppv frdhrapr ehaavat hc nygreangr pbyhzaf). Not really any calculations to perform...